# Проблема получения данных из room во ViewModel, используя Transformations.map

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, viewmodel

У нас есть recyclerview, ViewModel и room, из которого необходимо получать данные во ViewModel, после чего отобразить их в recyclerview.
Во ViewModel необходимо вытащить данные из Flow, после чего отобразить их в recyclerview.
Проблема заключается в том, что во ViewModel не удаётся получить данные из Room.

**DB0ViewModel.kt:**

```
class DB0ViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app) {
    
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<DataModel>>()
    init {
        val db0 = DB0.getDB0(app)
        var dataList = ArrayList<DataModel>()
        dataList.add(DataModel("test1", "test1", "tes1")) //+
        
        val DB0LiveData = db0.getDao().GetAll().asLiveData()
        Transformations.map(DB0LiveData, { list -> //-
            list.forEach{
                dataList.add(DataModel(it.id.toString(), it.Column0.toString(), it.Column1.toString()))
            }
        })
        
        dataList.add(DataModel("test2", "test2", "test2")) //+
        liveData.value = dataList
        
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
...
db0viewmodel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DB0ViewModel::class.java)//vm
        db0viewmodel.liveData.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
            initial(it)
        })
...
private fun initial(db0: ArrayList<DataModel>) {
        recyclerView = binding.recyclerViewData
        adapter = DataAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setList(db0)
        recyclerView.invalidate()
    }
```

**DB0Dao.kt:**

```
...
@Query("SELECT * FROM table0")
    fun GetAll(): Flow<List<DB0Entity>>
...
```

Необходимо отметить, что статичные данные, добавляемые в DB0ViewModel  (помеченные комментарием +) добавляются без проблем. Также ранее при использовании .getDao().GetAll().asLiveData().observe(this){ list-> ...
в MainActivity получить данные также удавалось.
В чём может быть проблема и как её можно решить?

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: А в чём суть вопроса? Почему нельзя из базы сразу получить данные в виде `LiveData<ArrayList<DataModel>>`?
 `Transformations.map()` возвращает `LiveData` нужного типа и вы должны подписаться на неё, чтобы получать преобразованные данные, а функция преобразования должна вернуть данные в нужном виде, а не пихать их во внешний список.

Comment: Проблема в том, что распаковку во ViewModel(в обход жизненного цикла observerа) можем совершить только посредством Transformations.map или Transformations.switchMap. Распаковку проводил ориентируясь на https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.

Comment: Вы что-то очень странное делете. `Transformations.map` выглядит очень лишним. По идее всё должно работать и так: `val liveData: LiveData<List<DataModel>>    init { liveData = db0.getDao().GetAll().asLiveData() }`. Ну и вместо `recyclerView.invalidate()` надо написать `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Можно без велосипедов и трансформаций из базы получить данные сразу в желаемых объектах:   https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#return-subset

Comment: Указанный выше способ сработал бы в случае, когда мы вытаскиваем данные в Activity, но в случае проведения данных манипуляций во ViewModel оно не сработало, по итогу наткнулся на Transformations в качестве способа работы с иcпускаемыми данными до того, как они достигнут Activity. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#return-subset (use vpn). 
*Данные уже находятся в виде объекта DB0Entity

Comment: Нет никакой разницы кто запрашивает эти данные - их выдаёт `room` в каком вам угодно виде. Но если уж так надо, то лучше конвертнуть сам `flow` оператором `map`, а уж после `asLiveData()` (если оно вам нужно) и всё решение в одну строку: `val liveData = DB0.getDB0(app).getDao().GetAll().map { list -> list.map { DataModel(it.id.toString(), it.Column0.toString(), it.Column1.toString())} }.asLiveData()`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, не понятно зачем вам liveData и Transformations, если у вас уже есть [flow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow), которое можно трансформировать итд.

```
db0.getDao().GetAll().map(...)
```

Во-вторых, по вопросу. Transformations.map вернула вам livedata, вы на нее не подписались и она умерла примерно сразу.
Чтобы заработал строчка с минусом, должно быть примерно так:

```
val liveData = Transformations.map(db0.getDao().GetAll().asLiveData(), {
        it.map{ (DB0Entity)-> 
             DataModel(it.id.toString(), it.Column0.toString(), it.Column1.toString())}
    }
})
```

в activity не надо каждый раз в observe создавать адаптер и прочее, это надо сделать один раз. В observe останется примерно:

```
db0viewmodel.livedata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    adapter.submitList(it)
}
```

В третьих, если вы хотите сами наполнять dataList, там где у вас плюсики, и из room'а, там где минус, то понадобится комбинировать два источника, например через MediatorLiveData.

ЗЫ сорри за возможные опечатки в коде